# What does arrays.length -1 mean in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem understanding what `array.length-1` means in my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){ 
    int[] array = new int[]{23, 75, 982, 22, 74, 45, 0, 76};
    for (int i=0; i< array.length -1; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: If you want to print all of the array elements, you don't want the -1, just `i < array.length;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your array has 8 elements, so `array.length=8`.

Therefore `array.length-1` = `8-1` = `7`.

You are running the loop from when `i` is `0`, until `i` is **less than** `7`. So it will run from `i=0` to `i=6`.

To traverse the entire array, you need to run it from `i=0` to `i=7` instead.

So change

```
i< array.length -1
```

to

```
i < array.length
```

or

```
i <= array.length - 1
```

Answer (score -3):

to make it super clear let us understand it the other way round. The length of your array here is 8. When talking about indexing of arrays,we know that index always starts from 0. The reason behind arr.length-1 is, we are looping all the elements from i=0 to i=6 as array lenght=8 and i<8-1 means i<7 so it would result in printing only from 0 to 6.. So its going to print elements only upto :[23,75,982,22,74,45,0]. Code should be changed from i<arr.length-1 to i<arr.length and you will print all values. Specially,arr.length-1 is used only when working with i+1 elements (Finding duplicates,etc.) because there, we don't want the index to go out of bounds.

For an array of length=3 when i=0, "next element exists only for 0 which is 1, and for 1 which is 2. There exists no next element for the 3rd element". Hope it gave you some clarity. Cheers.